How to debug finish_bundle not being called on Google Cloud Dataflow?
This is the code of the main and transform I'm using in the dataflow:
# main.py
    with Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
        _ = (
            pipeline
            | "Read input file" >> ReadFromText(options.input_file)
            | "Execute" >> Execute()
            | "Write CSV File" >> WriteToText(options.output_file)
        )

# execute.py
class Execute(beam.PTransform):
    def expand(self, pcollection: PCollection[str]) -> PCollection[str]:
        return pcollection | "Execute" >> beam.ParDo(ExecuteFn())


class ExecuteFn(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self):
        self._lines: list[str] = []

    def process(self, element: str) -> Iterator[str]:
        self._lines.append(element)
        yield element

    def start_bundle(self) -> None:
        log.error("Starting bundle")
        self._lines = []

    def finish_bundle(self) -> None:
        log.error(f"Finishing bundle, outputting {len(self._lines)} lines")
        for line in self._lines:
            log.error(f"Outputting line: {line}")

Here's the full working repro on github: https://github.com/davidreisbr/dataflow-bug. To use it see run.sh and change some vars at the top.
The code run was expected on the direct runner and in unit tests, but in Dataflow start_bundle and finish_bundle are never called.
What I've tried:

To ensure finish_bundle is really never called I've added log statements to the start_bundle and finish_bundle. In unit tests and with the direct runner these messages show up, as is executed the behavior. In GCP's dataflow neither happens. I'm sure the logging works because I have used it elsewhere.
To eliminate the possibility it's a recent bug, I've tried using Apache Beam 2.56 and 2.55.1, and had the same problem.


log = structlog.stdlib.get_logger(): have you tried not using structlog?
